# Mordecai: Esther's uncle?

Tags: family-members, megillat-esther, esther--the-woman

The *m'gila* says clearly that *Ester* was "*bas dodo*", which seems to mean she was the daughter of *Mord'chay*'s uncle, i.e., his first cousin. The *targum* renders this as "*b'ras achvoy*". Does that mean "his niece"? If not, then where does the common claim that *Ester* was *Mord'chay*'s niece come from? Alternatively, if so, then is there a commentary on the *m'gila* that says explicitly that she was his cousin?

Comment: It seems Ester, at least, was of the latter opinion http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55338/759

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R' Ari Zivotofsky has a nice article on this subject, explaining the possible reasons for this misconception:
https://www2.biu.ac.il/JH/Parasha/eng/purim/ziv.html

Comment: I've accepted this, and I thank you, R'Dave, for the link, but still wonder whether someone can translate _b'ras achvoy_ for me (as asked for in the question).

Comment: אחבוי is a contraction of אח אבוהי , meaning "the brother of his father." ("Brother" would be אחוי or אחוהי.) I now see that this was noted in the comments to Josh Waxman's post on the topic: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2006/11/was-mordechai-esthers-uncle-or-first_17.html

Comment: Perhaps you should consider summarizing the relevant portions here.

Comment: Basically: Mordechai was Esther's cousin. At some point, because he was much older and raised her, someone started saying "Uncle Mordechai", and somehow it stuck. (To make it worse, the verse says "Esther the daughter of Avichayil, [the] uncle [of] Mordechai"; someone may have erroneously heard the soundbite "uncle Mordechai", though the full sentence can't parse that way.) Rabbi Zivotovsky's article even catches a very great Torah scholar (who certainly knew better) once slipping up and saying "Uncle Mordechai."

Comment: Thanks, @Shalom! The article also mentions that two early non-Jewish translations rendered the verse incorrectly, which introduced this erroneous idea into Catholic tradition, from whence it may have spread.

Comment: Ibn Ezra on the [Megilla 8:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.8.1?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en ) and Metzudos Dovid on [Ezra {yes, Ezra} 2:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.2.2?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en ) both  refer to Mordechai as Esther’s uncle. 

It seems to me that neither of Rabbi Dr. Ari Zivotofsky's answers will fit these facts. How come the Ibn Ezra and the  Metzudos Dovid refer to Mordechai as Esther’s uncle?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - I am stumped by your question. Any progress in the last 2 years since you asked this?

Answer (score 8):

See the [commentary of the Ibn Ezra on Esther 8:1 (page 30 in the linked document)](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/ebenezra-ester/ebenezra-ester01.pdf) where he says that Mordechai was Esther's uncle.

Comment: yerushalayim, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing up this source! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. I hope you'll look around the site and find other material to your liking, perhaps including our 85 other [tag:megillat-esther] questions. Also, check out [*Purim - Mi Yodeya?*](http://s.tk/miyodeya)!

Comment: [Here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/mehokek/mehokek76.pdf) is an alternate version of Ibn Ezra's commentary in standard format (i.e. pesuqim on top, peirush on bottom).

Comment: [Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_34547_75.pdf) is Esther 8:1 with Peirush HaRaMBa"M, which states that "Esther told the king, 'Your advisor, Mordekhai, is my uncle, my father's brother. And he raised me [...]." (my translation)

Could this perhaps mean that Esther _lied_ to King Ahhashwerosh saying that Mordekhai was her uncle when, in fact, he was her cousin and husband?