# How did Esther reveal to Achashveroch that Mordechai is her husband

Tags: midrash, megillat-esther, tractate-megillah, esther--the-woman, mordechai

Avrohom ordered Sarah to say that she is his sister (he was afraid that Egyptian kill him). How was Esther not afraid  that Achashverosh kills Mordechai? (Esther 8, 1<sup>[1]</sup>)

#### She was the wife of Mordechai.

. 
The Gemara (Megila 13A) says.

> A Tanna taught in the name of R`Meir: Read not 'for a daughter' [le-bath], but 'for a house' [le-bayith].(Ester 2, 7)
>
> Similarly it says: But the poor man had nothing save one little ewe lamb, which he had brought up and reared; and it grew up together with him, and with his children; it did eat of his own morsel, and drank of his own cup, and lay in his bosom, and was unto him as a daughter.

---

> [1] On that day did the king Ahasuerus give the house of Haman the Jews' enemy unto Esther the queen. And Mordecai came before the king; for Esther had told what he was unto her.
>
> א  בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא, נָתַן הַמֶּלֶךְ אֲחַשְׁוֵרוֹשׁ לְאֶסְתֵּר הַמַּלְכָּה, אֶת-בֵּית הָמָן, צֹרֵר היהודיים (הַיְּהוּדִים); וּמָרְדֳּכַי, בָּא לִפְנֵי הַמֶּלֶךְ--כִּי-הִגִּידָה אֶסְתֵּר, מַה הוּא-לָהּ. ‏

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I have no source for this, but my reading of [Esther 8:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Esther.8.1) is that she revealed to Achashverosh only that Mordechai was her *[cousin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/mordecai-esthers-uncle)*, and did not tell him that he was also her husband.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/mordecai-esthers-uncle#comment94281_36196

Comment: But the claim that Sarah is Avraham's sister works much better because that excludes her from being his wife. I'm not sure how well it would work for Esther to claim Mordechai was her uncle, considering it doesn't Halachically exclude her from being his wife as well.

Comment: @user6618, so you think _Achashverosh_ was going to go around killing everyone who could possibly be _Ester_'s husband?

Comment: @msh210 Valid point.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in Tosfot in Masechet Megila.

Tosfot in Masechet Megila asked. After that Esther has an intentional marital relationship with Achashverosh (according to Gemara Megila 15a: Gemara Megila 15a: R`Abba said: It will not be [she said] according to the custom of every other day. Till now [I have associated with Ahasuerus] under compulsion, but now I will do so of my own will. And if I perish, I perish. As I am lost to my father's house so I shall be lost to thee.), why Mordechai gave not to him a Get. And answered that id he would give a Get, the knowledge of his marriage with Esther can be known by the kingdom (וא''ת אמאי לא היה מגרשה ותהא מותרת להחזירנה י''ל לפי שכל מעשה הגט הוא ע''פ עדים והיה ירא פן יתפרסם הדבר למלכות).

So from the tosfot we learn that this was a secret. So, as suggested @Scimonster, the opinion of Tosfot is that "she just said that he was her cousin and father figure"

Comment: You dont actually see that from Tosafot. Tosafot could easily be dealing with the earlier period before she revealed her identity.