# Esther’s and Mordechai’s relationship?

Tags: megillat-esther, esther--the-woman, mordechai

I have heard many times over the years that Mordechai was esther’s Uncle. Yet it says in the Megillah itself that Mordechai was esther’s cousin! (Esther 2:7) 
Does anyone know of any sources that say that Mordechai  was esther’s uncle?

Comment: some reading with sources https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_mordechai_and_esther/

Comment: This has been discussed already ,Ibn Ezra,but most hold they were cousins ,in fact when Rav Dovid Feinstein discusses their relationship he says cousins

Comment: See if your question might be the same as the one answered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6479/1569)